# Append directive to body

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a popup directive, and I would like to compile and append it to body. Is there a simpler way then recompiling and appending directive to body.

```
 link: function (scope, element) {
     $('body').append($compile('html')(scope.new()))
  }
```

I don't want to compile the directive twice, first time automatically, and the second time manually. If there is a property or setting, that will automatically append the directive to body, that would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your custom directive in the right place within you page's html, and then use `transclude` to swap that with anything you put in the directive's `template`?

Comment: OK, whatever suits you best. Also, is this `$('body').append` jQuery? I don't think it's a good practice to use it like that with AngularJS. Good luck anyway, these were just my observations.

Comment: I am using angular.element.